# Location of PHP _POST parsing code

Tags: php

Does anyone know where I can find the code PHP uses to parse post data into `$_POST` and `$_FILES`? I'm trying to figure out how it handles unescaped filenames, but I can't seem to find it. It doesn't help that it's a huge project and I have no idea where to even look, and searching isn't helping.

Comment: In this case, I think experimenting with input and output would provide more insight than digging through some parsing source code.

Comment: I think the [hackers guide to the Zend Engine](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) will help you on your way here

Comment: check in `rfc1867.c`, I think that's where I found that stuff once.

Comment: This link has a good sample on how to do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707078/post-renamed-filename-from-upload-to-database

Comment: @redelman431, hes asking about the php engine source code written in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `main/rfc1867.c`. See within `rfc1867_post_handler`, around where it is parsing the Content-Disposition header. The function uses `php_ap_getword_conf` to parse the filename value.